# How to set the columns in dataframe to the values obtained from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a DataFrame with two columns, `Size` being the size of the object and `Description` being the item description. Some cells in the `Size` column are already filled, so I wanted to focus on the empty ones like this:

```
|Size|Description  |
-----+-------------|
|    |Red-Round-L  |
|    |Blue-Square-M|
```

I want to fill in the empty cells in `Size` column using the values in the `Description` columns so that it will look like this:

```
|Size |Description  |
------+-------------|
|  L  |Red-Round-L  |
|  M  |Blue-Square-M|
```

I tried using this:

```py
df.loc[df['Size'] == '', 'Size'] = df['Description'].str.split('-')[2] #Because the item size is 3rd element
```

But it threw an error:

```py
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

How do I get the item size from each cell of the column `Description` and fill it in the cells of `Size`?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe so not adding an answer but use str accessor to extract the element from split. df.loc[df['Size'] == '', 'Size'] = df['Description'].str.rsplit('-').str[-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use same boolean mask:

```
df.loc[df['Size'] == '', 'Size'] = df.loc[df['Size'] == '','Description'].str.split('-')[2]
```

Because thats the only way lengths on each side are matched. What you were trying to do is selecting all columns on the right while only those on the left where `df.Size == ''`. Which is only gonna work if all rows fit this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the argument `expand` (see more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)):

```
df.loc[df["Size"] == '', "Size"] = df["Description"].str.split('-', expand = True).iloc[:,[-1]].values.reshape(-1)
```

The difference is that without using `expand` you get:

```
0      [Red, Round, L]
1    [Blue, Square, M]
```

So you can't access to every "3nd position". Now, if `expand = True` you get:

```
      0       1  2
0   Red   Round  L
1  Blue  Square  M
```

So you can access to the last column (`.iloc[:,[-1]]`). Last thing is to reshape the obtained array to a 1-dimensional array (`.reshape(-1)`)